# Using beans from another project

Tags: spring, context.xml

I'm a novice on spring, I started to develop a new application with 2 modules, each one is a project, the first one is a java project, it contains the services beans declared in a `servicescontext.xml`, the second project is a web application that uses the first project. I need to declare beans in the web application that use the services beans (the java project).

Comment: This question is for 6 years ago and I hope you see this comment. Could you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

I guess this sort of depends on how you want to package the webapp. One solution that can work for you is to package the service-module as a jar file and then put it in the WEB-INF/lib of your webapp. You can then reference the other xml-file(s) from your webapp configuration. Take a look at this:

```
<import resource="servicescontext.xml"/>
```

Add "classpath" to reference the xml-file in the service-module jar file:

```
<import resource="classpath:servicescontext.xml"/>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work, i developped a simple application with spring with a simple bean(add), and a generated the jar, in the web application i addes the jar to the lib, and i tried to import the bean add, but, it doesn't work;
If any one has a solution thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven. Packge first project as jar and add its dependency in second project's pom.xml. You will be able to reference all the beans defined in first project.